# React Component receive props but doesn't render it, why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise, react-router

I have a page displaying user's books. 
On this MyBooks page, React component mount. When it's mounted it fetch user's books through API. Then it update component's state with user's books.

1. mount component
2. fetch books through API
3. when we have results, update component's state
4. **render again BooksList component (but it's not happening)**

---

Here is my code for `MyBooks` component :

```
class MyBooks extends Component {
  // TODO: fetch user info
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      books: [],
      errors: []
    };

    this.fetchBooks = this.fetchBooks.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('component mounted!');
    this.fetchBooks();
  }

  fetchBooks() {
    let _this = this;
    BooksLibraryApi.getBooks().then(foundBooks => {
      console.log('books found:', foundBooks);
      _this.setState({
        books: foundBooks
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log('MyBooks state:', this.state);
    return (
      <Section>
        <Container>
          <h1>My books</h1>
          <BooksList books={this.state.books} />
        </Container>
      </Section>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(MyBooks);
```

Here is the result for `console.log('books found:', foundBooks)`:

[image: console output]

---

Here is my code for `BooksList` component :

```
class BooksList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log('BooksList props:', this.props);
    return (
      <Columns breakpoint="mobile">
        {this.props.books.map((book, i) => {
          console.log(book);
          return (
            <Columns.Column
              key={i}
              mobile={{ size: 'half' }}
              desktop={{ size: 2 }}
            >
              <BookCard book={book} />
            </Columns.Column>
          );
        })}
      </Columns>
    );
  }
}

export default BooksList;
```

Here is the code for `BookCard` component:

```
class BookCard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log('props', props);
    this.readBook = this.readBook.bind(this);
    this.addBook = this.addBook.bind(this);
    this.deleteBook = this.deleteBook.bind(this);
    this.wantBook = this.wantBook.bind(this);
  }

  readBook() {
    BooksLibraryApi.readBook(this.props.book.id);
  }

  addBook() {
    BooksLibraryApi.addBook(this.props.book.id);
  }

  wantBook() {
    BooksLibraryApi.wantBook(this.props.book.id);
  }

  deleteBook(e) {
    BooksLibraryApi.deleteBook(this.props.book.id, e);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card-book">
        <Link to={`/book/${this.props.book.id}`}>
          {this.props.book.doHaveThumbnail ? (
            <Image
              alt="Cover"
              src={this.props.book.thumbnailUrl}
              size={'2by3'}
            />
          ) : (
            <div className="placeholder">
              <span>{this.props.book.title}</span>
            </div>
          )}
        </Link>
        <Button fullwidth color="primary" size="small" onClick={this.wantBook}>
          Add to wishlist
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(BookCard);
```

The `console.log` in `BooksList` component is not called. Which means that the component is render only one time, when the `this.props.books` array is empty.

I don't understand why `BooksList` is not rendered again when his props are updated (when `MyBooks` component has his state updated).

Strange behavior: I'm using React Router, and when I first click on the link "My books" (which go to my `MyBooks` component), it doesn't work, but when I click again on it, everything works fine. Which means that something is wrong with rendering / component's lifecyles.

Thanks.

Comment: `console.log('books found:', foundBooks);` is this line printing the correct result?

Comment: Can you try to add before the `return()` of the render function of `Booklist` this console.log: `console.log(this.props);`

And same thing in `MyBooks`: `console.log(this.state);`
And this is not util in your code : `this.fetchBooks = this.fetchBooks.bind(this);`

Comment: @MayankShukla yes, I edited post to show results.

Comment: @CraftyMonkey I updated post :)

Comment: We see the both re-renders according to the console.log on the screenshot. There might be something broken in <BookCard />

Comment: @samb102 from what I see, we don't go in `this.props.book.map`, but why ? Is it seeing it empty ?

Comment: @samb102 I can add `BookCard` component's code if you want, but I doubt it would be useful.

Comment: @HJerem you mean it doesn't enter in `.map` and you don't see any `console.log(book)` ?

Comment: @samb102 yep, the screenshot of the console is all I got. So yes, `console.log(book)` is never executed.

Comment: The problem lies on BookCard, please post the code for the component

Comment: I agree with @Dupocas, Do you have any error message in the console ?

Comment: Added `BookCard` code.

Comment: @CraftyMonkey Of course not, or I would have post it here.

Comment: Is not related to the question but get used to arrow functions so that you not longer need to bind every single method

Comment: So no idea ? :(